# Apple Script:how to save user input to text file

Tags: python-3.x, applescript

I'm using apple script in my python app, how do i save the input provided by a user as a text file?

```
 firstname = """
    display dialog "Enter your first name " default answer "" ¬
    buttons {"Submit"}
    """
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider either of the following solutions:

### Solution A: Using Python to save user input to a text file.

```py
import os

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

userPrompt = """
    tell application "Finder"
      activate
      text returned of (display dialog "Enter your first name " default answer "" buttons {"Submit"})
    end tell
    """

proc = Popen(['osascript', '-'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)

firstname, error = proc.communicate(userPrompt)

filePath = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Desktop', 'result.txt')

with open(filePath, 'w') as file:
    file.write(firstname)
```

- This utilizes the [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) Constructor to shell out the `osascript` command which essentially runs the AppleScript.
- Currently the input provided by the user is written to a file named `results.txt` which is saved to the *Desktop* folder. The [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) module is utilized to determine the destination filepath. You'll need to change this as necessary.
- Finally we [write the user input to file](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) using [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open).

---

### Solution B: Using AppleScript to save user input to a text file from Python.

Another way is to *shell-out* utilizing AppleScript's [`do shell script`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW40) command to save the user input to a text file instead.

In which case your `.py` file would be as follows:

```py
userPrompt = """
    tell application "Finder"
      activate
      set firstname to text returned of (display dialog "Enter your first name " default answer "" buttons {"Submit"})
      do shell script "echo " & quoted form of firstname & " > ~/Desktop/result.txt"
      return firstname
    end tell
    """

proc = Popen(['osascript', '-'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)

firstname, error = proc.communicate(userPrompt)

# print(firstname)
```

The line that reads:

```
do shell script "echo " & quoted form of firstname & " > ~/Desktop/result.txt"
```

essentially utilizes the shells [`echo`](https://ss64.com/osx/echo.html) utility to redirect/save the user input to a file named `results.txt`, which again is saved to the *Desktop* folder.